# How to refresh the facebook like url in reactjs (using facebook-sdk CDN)

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook's like button as generated by [facebook's like button configurator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#configurator). However in order to get facebook-sdk to finish loading before the Like button, I had to use something called [react-load-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script) and make a my own wrapper component for the like button html I got from the configurator.

my like button

```
class Like extends React.Component {
  state = {
    facebookLoaded: false
  };

  handleFacebookLoaded = () => this.setState({
    facebookLoaded: true
  });

  FacebookSDK = () => <>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <Script
      async defer crossOrigin="anonymous"
      url="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3&appId=391623981325884&autoLogAppEvents=1"
      onLoad={this.handleFacebookLoaded}
    />
  </>;

  render() {
    return <>
      <this.FacebookSDK />
      {this.state.facebookLoaded
        ? <div class="fb-like" data-href={this.props.url} data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" />
        : null}
    </>;
  }
}
```

In my code all the script loading stuff actually happens in App.jsx, but I moved it into one class just to show a simple version.

This part seems to work fine, the issue lies when changing the url passed to data-href.

I checked the react dom in the browser and the data-href is actually being updated properly, however this does not affect the actual url that is being used by the like button, unless I do a full page refresh. I'm assuming this has to do with how the data-href is being used by facebook-sdk. (edit: after testing I'm not sure anymore)

I've found many questions about this on Stack Overflow, however none of them seem to be based off the CDN version of facebook buttons

From what I understand, the div containing the href needs to be placed out and back into the DOM in order for the facebook-sdk to detect a change, but I don't know how to do this in react without a full page refresh. Also I'm not certain this is even the right solution.

-- Update --
I just noticed something else that seems like useful information. If I navigate to the page with the like button, then it doesn't show up. It will only show up if the page refreshes. I tested it by moving the part that loads the script into the like component (like in the example shown above) and that didn't change the behavior at all.

-- more experimenting --
I wrote an event handler that takes all the facebook related jsx out of the dom and back in (by toggling a button) However when all the code goes back into the dom (both jsx and html), the UI for the button does not come back. I'm really now sure how this is possible as I'm literally reloading the script and everything facebook related so this should be equivalent to a page refresh no?

Comment: The JS SDK goes through your document _once_ on initialization, to look for elements to parse into social plugins. If you change the DOM content later on, you will have to explicitly trigger this again - that’s what `FB.XFBML.parse` is for. (That however won’t refresh any plugins based on that you changed any data attributes - you will have to create a whole new `<div class="fb-like" …>` element, insert it in place of the currently rendered plugin, and then call the mentioned method.)

Comment: @misorude I could kiss you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue thanks to misorude. The part I was missing was calling `window.FB.XFBML.parse()`. I didn't realize I could access `FB` the same way using the CDN. If anyone is looking for a react solution here is the working code:

```
class Like extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        url: props.url,
    }
  }

  handleChangePage() {
    let likeBtn = document.createElement('div');
    likeBtn.className = "fb-like";
    likeBtn.setAttribute("data-href", this.props.url);
    likeBtn.setAttribute("data-width", "");
    likeBtn.setAttribute("data-layout", "button_count");
    likeBtn.setAttribute("data-action", "like");
    likeBtn.setAttribute("data-size", "large");
    likeBtn.setAttribute("data-show-faces", "true");
    likeBtn.setAttribute("data-share", "true");

    let likePanel = document.getElementById("like-panel");
    likePanel.removeChild(likePanel.childNodes[0]);
    likePanel.appendChild(likeBtn);

    window.FB.XFBML.parse(likePanel)
    this.setState({ url: this.props.url });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleChangePage();
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.url !== this.state.url) 
      this.handleChangePage();

    return <div id="like-panel">
      {this.props.facebookLoaded
        ? <div className="fb-like" data-href={this.props.url} data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" />
        : null}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

I moved the CDN out of this component so that it only loads the sdk once for the whole app.